# SQLBrite how to pass parameter to createQuery

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlbrite

I am using sqlbrite for my chatting app. I need to observe a database, but the range is not fixed.

```
Observable<Query> messages = db.createQuery("messages", "SELECT * FROM users WHERE timestamp > ? ");
```

I need to pass in an argument `newestMessage.sentTime`, but newestMessage keeps updating as soon as a new message comes. So I cant just pass in the current `newestMessage` as argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of a single query execution never change and represent a snapshot. To get more messages, you have to re-execute the query, i.e., call `createQuery` again.